# how to split a string to list of objects

Tags: c#, list

i have a string `"105,1,13312;105,2,13314;105,3,13316;106,1,13318;106,2,13320;106,3,13322"`

i need to convert the string into a list

```
List<MyClass> registers = new List<MyClass>();

class MyClass{
        public int TOT_ID;
        public int phaze;
        public int register;
    }
```

i tried

```
registers = registersArr.Split(';')
               .Select(x => x.Split(','))
               .Where(x => x.Length == 3)
               .ToList(x => x[0], x => x[1], x=> x[2]);
```

i get an error

```
Error   191 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Use `Cast` method, as the `Select` method is for a `List`, not the `Array`

Comment: where to use it, cast to what?

Comment: `Cast<string>`, as you have an array of `string`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: And do you have `using System.Linq;` reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot

```
using System.Linq;
```

and then:

```
registers = registersArr.Split(';')
                        .Select(x => x.Split(','))
                        .Where(x => x.Length == 3)
```

Change from here:

```
                        .Select(x => new MyClass 
                               { 
                                    TOT_ID = int.Parse(x[0]), 
                                    phaze = int.Parse(x[1]), 
                                    register = int.Parse(x[2]) 
                               })
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 string s = "105,1,13312;105,2,13314;105,3,13316;106,1,13318;106,2,13320;106,3,13322";
        List<MyClass> registers = new List<MyClass>();
        registers = s.Split(';')
            .Select(x => new MyClass() {
                TOT_ID = x[0], 
                phaze = x[1],
                register =x[2] 
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

registers = registersArr.Split(';')
.Select(x => new MyClass { TOT_ID = int.Parse(x.Split(',')[0]), phaze = int.Parse(x.Split(',')[1]), register = int.Parse(x.Split(',')[2]) })
.ToList();